# Can't find a mistake in my Back-Propagation algorithm in my Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I've spent hours but I just don't see it.
I know the mistake is in backprop part because when I replace it with Andrew Ng's code it works. But I can't relate his code (from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_Eamf8MHwU)) to the math that I'm following (and that makes sense to me) from 3blue1brown (from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8&list=PLZHQObOWTQDNU6R1_67000Dx_ZCJB-3pi&index=4)).

The problem is that the shapes I'm getting for the derivatives of weight matrices (dLdW1, dLdW2) don't make sense. W1 is shaped (4,2) and so dLdW1 should be too (instead it's 2,1). W2 is shaped (1,4) and so dLdW2 should be too (instead it's 4,400). So I'm getting one of the dimensions right but not the other and I can't figure out why.

Note on notation: where I write eg dW2 I am referring to the derivative of W2 to the immediate prior term, in this case Z2. Where I write dLdW2 I am referring to the ultimate derivative against the cost function (ie full backprop through the entire network).

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1) 

from planar_utils import plot_decision_boundary, sigmoid, load_planar_dataset, load_extra_datasets
X, Y = load_planar_dataset()

def sigmoid(z):
    """The sigmoid function."""
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
    """Derivative of the sigmoid function."""
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))

def define_NN_structure(X,Y):
    n_x = X.shape[0] #input neurons
    n_h = 4 #hidden neurons
    n_y = Y.shape[0] #output neurons
    return n_x, n_h, n_y

def initialize_params(n_x,n_h,n_y):
    W1 = np.random.randn(n_h,n_x)*0.01 #n[L] by n[L-1]
    B1 = np.zeros((n_h,1)) #n[L] by 1 
    W2 = np.random.randn(n_y,n_h)*0.01 #n[L] by n[L-1]
    B2 = np.zeros((n_y,1)) #n[L] by 1 
    return W1, B1, W2, B2

def forward_prop(W1, B1, W2, B2):
    Z1 = W1 @ X + B1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = W2 @ A1 + B2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)
    return Z1, A1, Z2, A2

def compute_cost(A2, Y):
    m = Y.shape[1]
    L = 1/m * np.sum((A2 - Y)**2) #MSE
    return L

def backward_prop(X, Y, Z1, A1, Z2, A2):
    m = Y.shape[1]
    dA2 = 2*np.abs(A2 - Y) #1,400
    dZ2 = sigmoid_prime(Z2) #1,400
    dW2 = A1 #4,400
    dB2 = np.ones((1,A1.shape[1]))#1,400
    dA1 = W2 #1,4
    dZ1 = sigmoid_prime(Z1) #4,400
    dW1 = X #2,400
    dB1 = np.ones((1,X.shape[1])) #1,400

    dLdW2 = 1/m * dW2 @ dZ2.T @ dA2
    dLdB2 = 1/m * dB2 @ dZ2.T @ dA2
    dLdW1 = 1/m * dW1 @ dZ1.T @ dA1.T @ dZ2 @ dA2.T
    dLdB1 = 1/m * dB1 @ dZ1.T @ dA1.T @ dZ2 @ dA2.T
    return dLdW2, dLdB2, dLdW1, dLdB1, dA2, dZ2, dW2, dB2, dA1, dZ1, dW1, dB1

def update_params(W1, B1, W2, B2, dLdW2, dLdB2, dLdW1, dLdB1, alpha):
    W1 = W1 - alpha * dLdW1
    B1 = B1 - alpha * dLdB1
    W2 = W2 - alpha * dLdW2
    B2 = B2 - alpha * dLdB2    
    return W1, B1, W2, B2 

n_x, n_h, n_y = define_NN_structure(X,Y)
W1, B1, W2, B2 = initialize_params(n_x, n_h, n_y)

for i in range(3000):
    Z1, A1, Z2, A2 = forward_prop(W1, B1, W2, B2)
    L = compute_cost(A2, Y)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print('Loss is: ' + str(L))
    dLdW2, dLdB2, dLdW1, dLdB1, dA2, dZ2, dW2, dB2, dA1, dZ1, dW1, dB1 = backward_prop(X, Y, Z1, A1, Z2, A2)
    W1, B1, W2, B2 = update_params(W1, B1, W2, B2, dLdW2, dLdB2, dLdW1, dLdB1, 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

After more time, I figured it out. Here's the right set of equations for backprop:

```
    m = Y.shape[1]
    dA2 = 1/m * 2*(A2 - Y) #1,400
    dZ2 = sigmoid_prime(Z2) #1,400
    dW2 = A1 #4,400
    dB2 = np.ones((1,A1.shape[1]))#1,400
    dA1 = W2 #1,4
    dZ1 = sigmoid_prime(Z1) #4,400
    dW1 = X #2,400
    dB1 = np.ones((1,X.shape[1])) #1,400

    delta2 = dA2 * dZ2 #1,400
    dLdW2 = delta2 @ dW2.T #1,4
    dLdB2 = delta2 @ dB2.T #1,1

    delta1 = delta2.T @ dA1 * dZ1.T #400,4
    dLdW1 = delta1.T @ dW1.T #4,2
    dLdB1 = delta1.T @ dB1.T #4,1
```

2 things were wrong in my original approach:
1. turns out some terms need to be element-multiplied, not matrix-multiplied (specifically the `dZ` terms)
2. the order of the terms was wrong. I'm sure you could preserve the original order with enough transposing, but this felt the simplest once I understood what to do.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlcnxUlrtek) was super helpful.

Comment: Well, I'm glade you found the issue.